# JFrame is loaded late

Tags: java

My code is:

```
    solveDb_userfileInconsistency solve = new solveDb_userfileInconsistency();
    solve.setVisible(true);

    try {
        solve.solveIt();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

"solveIt" method returns after 30 seconds and until it returns, frame isn't installed properly but after solveIt method returns, the frame gets installed properly but what i want is that before going into solveIt method, the frame should be properly on the screen. Is there any method that can wait the frame's installation and then calls that solveIt method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're probably doing all of this on the UI thread. Don't do that - make `solveIt` execute on a background thread, calling into the UI thread using [`SwingUtilities`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) if it needs to update/query the UI. Basically, you shouldn't do significant work in the UI thread - see the [Swing concurrency tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at SwingWorker Class. It is used to do the background processes without stopping the frame to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the event-dispatching thread for short lived GUI related code. Long running tasks should be execute in their own threads as stated in the other answers.

Let me just complement the other answers with some interesting links:

- [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- [Threads and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html)
- [Using a Swing Worker Thread](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads2.html)

Note that the two links points to somewhat old but relevant documentation of JFC. Nowadays `SwingWorker` is included in the Standard [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).